# Can't see the messages I'm posting in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

[image]
I'm creating a yik yak clone and I can't seem to see the messages I post in the textField(string) on Parse. Is there something wrong I'm doing in my code that's not letting it show up on Parse?

```
  @IBAction func postPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    if(currLocation != nil){
        let testObj = PFObject(className: "BubbleTest")

        testObj["userName"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
        //testObj["profileName"] = PFUser.valueForKey("profileName") as! String
        //testObj["photo"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.valueForKey("photo") as! PFFile
        testObj["textField"] = self.textField.text
        testObj["location"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: currLocation!.latitude , longitude: currLocation!.longitude)
        testObj["count"] = 0
        testObj["replies"] = 0
        testObj.saveInBackground()


        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        alert()
    }
```

Comment: have you debug your code? the saveinBackground() function is executed?

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know many developer friends of mine who ran into a similar issue. I myself had this problem as well, now resolved. So hopefully I can provide some insight from what I learned querying data from Parse:

Try changing the ***numberOfSectionsInTableView*** method to **return 1** instead of 0 like so:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 1
}
```

You may need to also have some data structure to hold the users' posts (messages):

```
 var userPosts:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

Also, your table view could then have as many rows as you will have posts stored in userPosts:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userPosts.count
}
```

In ***cellForRowAtIndexPath***, replace this:

```
let object = PFObject(className: "BubbleTest")
```

**WITH THIS:**

```
let userPost : PFObject = self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject 
...

cell.message.text = userPost.objectForKey("message") as! String

return cell
}
```

This will set the text of your custom cell's message property to whatever the user's message is (i.e.: "Testing 1 2").

**Note:** These steps aren't intended to be the only steps needed to solve your problem. It is meant to guide you in the right direction with some basic steps.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing anything because you post it into the wrong class. According to the picture `BubbleTest` is the name of the class not `YikYakTest`

replace this line

```
   let testObj = PFObject(className: "YikYakTest")
```

by

```
let testObj = PFObject(className: "BubbleTest")
```

your code should look like :

**Note use saveInBackgroundWithBlock method so you could check if there is an error while saving**

```
 let testObj = PFObject(className: "BubbleTest")
    let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    testObj["userName"] = username
    testObj["textField"] = self.textField.text
    testObj["Location"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude:currLocation.latitude , longitude: currLocation.longitude)
    testObj["count"] = 0
    testObj["replies"] = 0
    testObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error :NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
           print("detail is saved")
           self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
          {
              print("error")
          }
    }
```

when you are saving **PFGeopoint** coordinates save it into `Location` column  not `location`

Comment: No no i had BubbleTest before and it still doesn't work

Comment: you want to save those info the bubbleTest class right ?

Comment: Yes I mistakenly put YikYakTest in this post but in my actually code it is bubbletest

Comment: So I used the code you put up and I still can't see the messages on Parse. Is there another reason this is not working?

Comment: try to take out this line `if(currLocation != nil){`

Comment: Still not able to see the messages. Do you think there's something wrong in the code for  testObj["textField"] = self.textField.text? Because I can see the username, the location, the count, and replies

Comment: Well I still had it there in my code but I still can't see the messages on Parse.

Comment: you should check to see if the textfield.text is empty .. if empty don't send no data to parse

Comment: What do you mean if its empty? I never took the textfield.text out of my code.

Comment: Empty as if the user didn't write anything into the text field

Comment: Well I'm user and I'm writing it in the textfield and I pressed the post button so the data should be sent to Parse

Comment: Try to hard code some message into the trxtfoeld object to see if you see it in parse

Comment: What do you mean by hardcode?Sorry for this by the way I'm fairly new to coding

Comment: 'testObj["textField"] = "we have some hardcoded values here "'